# I need to know the best mached mavsdk version for pymavlink 2.4.35

Tags: python, dronekit-python, dronekit, mavlink

Now I am trying to connect pymavlink and mavsdk to control drone. But all of the command works well (for example : land(), getposition() and so on..) but only hold() function does not run. I think this is the version problem. So I want to know the best mached mavsdk version for pymavlink 2.4.35. I think pymavlink 2.4.35 is the best suitable version. Additionally my python version is 3.9.7.

I have tried to use most current mavsdk version, but does not run.